# Ruby 2.2.0 fails to build on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I'm trying to build Ruby 2.2.0 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 and it always fails.

Here are the packages I'm installing beforehand.

```
DEPENDENCIES = %w{
  build-essential bison openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev git-core zlib1g
  zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libxml2-dev libgdbm3 libgdbm-dev autoconf
  libxslt-dev libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake pkg-config subversion libtool
  libffi-dev libncurses5-dev
}
```

Here's the error I'm getting.

```
linking shared-object fiddle.so
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/ruby-2.2.0/ext/fiddle'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/ruby-2.2.0'
STDERR: Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
/usr/bin/ld: ./libffi-3.2.1/.libs/libffi.a(raw_api.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
./libffi-3.2.1/.libs/libffi.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../../.ext/x86_64-linux/fiddle.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/fiddle/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1' --with-    bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
/usr/bin/ld: ./libffi-3.2.1/.libs/libffi.a(raw_api.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
./libffi-3.2.1/.libs/libffi.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../../.ext/x86_64-linux/fiddle.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/fiddle/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

This issue closely resembled what's described [here](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/690#issuecomment-68113987), but the solution given there is to install a library that I always install first anyway.

libffi-dev is one of the packages I always install first. `dpkg -s libffi-dev` shows version `Version: 3.1~rc1+r3.0.13-12` installed yet I still get the error I posted in the question.

#### Solution

It looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27881263/ruby-2-2-0-fails-to-build-on-ubuntu-14-04-1-lts#comment44379977_27881903) is the solution to the problem.

Comment: Probably not what you're after, but I'd suggest just using the Brightbox ruby https://www.brightbox.com/docs/ruby/ubuntu/

Comment: I'm maintaining a chef cookbook for Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS and I like to keep both a build-from-source and brightbox ppa recipe working. ;) https://github.com/chef-ubuntu/ruby

Comment: Right now I've just set my from-source recipe to stick w/ 2.1.5 because it compiles successfully.

Comment: I had the same issue (on OSX), but in my case libffi-dev was missing. Others I googled had the same root cause. Are you certain the dependencies you listed are installed correctly?

Comment: I'm using `apt-get install` for each of them. Beyond that I don't know how to check.

Comment: It seems that at least a while ago, there [was an issue](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=523869) with libffi-dev installing itself into an arch-specific subdirectory instead of into /usr/lib and /usr/include directly, and GCC not finding it. I'd try running `dpkg-query -L libffi-dev` and softlinking all listed `lib`s and `include`s from the arch subdirectory directly into `/usr/lib` and `/usr/include`. Then `make clean`, and try again.

Comment: I think u need to first do: sudo apt-get install libffi-dev https://twitter.com/ytbryan/status/548384288501006336

Comment: @ytbryan Did you read the thread before commenting? `libffi-dev` is one of the packages I always install first. `dpkg -s libffi-dev` shows version `Version: 3.1~rc1+r3.0.13-12` installed yet I still get the error I posted in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you can define a variable named `CFLAGS` that will be passed as extra parameters to the compiler(at least that's what I've gathered from it).

So, to be able to properly compile ruby 2.2.0, just run `CFLAGS=-fPIC` before your `./configure` call. Example:

`CFLAGS=-fPIC
./configure`

Obviously if you want to pass any params to `configure`, then do so. From there on your `make` command should work without any hiccups.

Answer (score 7):

Can you try the `ruby-install` tool?

It does a great job of installing ruby and its dependencies, libraries, etc.

https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install

- Other Ruby installers you may want to consider are [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv), [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build), [rvm](https://rvm.io/), and [Brightbox](https://www.brightbox.com/docs/ruby/ubuntu/).
- Even if your goal is to install Ruby from source, you may find it helpful to try a ruby installer, to figure out what steps your install may be missing and how to solve your error.

Can you verify that your libffi-dev is correct?

```
dpkg -s libffi-dev
```

I have Ubuntu 14 and Ruby 2.2.0 and my libffi-dev is showing:

```
Version: 3.1~rc1+r3.0.13-12
```

Whereas your error message shows your installation is trying to use a newer version:

```
libffi-3.2.1
```

Update...

> I ran dpkg -s libffi-dev and I got Version: 3.1~rc1+r3.0.13-12.

Good:

- Your system has the correct libffi, the same version in the official packages.
- Whereas your Ruby installation is attempting to use a different version.
- This mismatch shows that your Ruby installation is not finding your system libffi.

When I download Ruby 2.2.0 source, I see that the `fiddle` directory has a different `libffi` than my system:

```
➜  ruby-2.2.0  find . | grep libffi
./ext/fiddle/libffi-3.2.1
```

The libffi directory has it's own README, configure, and Makefile.

If you see the same on your system, you may want to try making it yourself, and possibly installing it too - though I don't know if that would overwrite your system libffi so perhaps proceed cautiously, or install into a custom directory:

```
./ext/fiddle/libffi-3.2.1
./configure
make
make install
```

If you get the same essential error and suggestion to compile with `-fPIC` then you can try that too. Head up to put `-fPIC` as the first arg because some people report that the arg doesn't work later on.

For example to add `-fPIC` on your compiler:

```
CC=gcc -fPIC ...
```

For example to use `-fPIC` on your configure:

```
CFLAGS=-fPIC ./configure
```

Comment: I ran `dpkg -s libffi-dev` and I got `Version: 3.1~rc1+r3.0.13-12`.

Comment: @RyanBurnette from the output: `/usr/bin/ld: ./libffi-3.2.1/.libs/libffi.a` — doesn't that mean `make` uses lib-ffi bundled with the Ruby install? Could it be a mismatch between the Ruby-supplied library and the system-installed headers?

Comment: I think you're right. That would also explain why ruby-installer works on the same setup without a hitch.

Comment: I got busy and never got into testing this further, but I started using ruby-install and I haven't had any more problems. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I just faced the same issue and just set the `CFLAGS` variable like so: `CFLAGS=-fPIC` . Then I ran `./configure` again and everything worked just fine. Note: I did compile the custom libffi that comes with 2.2.0 beforehand but it didn't fix the issue. Not sure if that's required though.

Comment: @Nikola Thank you, that is very good news. I'll add your successful result to the answer.

Comment: @NikolaIvanovNikolov It looks like this is the true solution to the original question. I wish you'd post this as an answer so I could make it the accepted solution.